# Protractor for Angular : wait all API calls of each page before testing

Tags: angular, api, protractor

What i want to do is to test my application by navigating to many pages of it, but what I want is that when i navigate from a page to another, I want all the API calls to be finished before doing actions (click on a button, etc...), and if an API call has failed, break the test and trigger an error.

My protractor.conf.js

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

EDIT : Example :

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { element, by, browser } from 'protractor';

describe('my App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('check log in', () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    page.navigateTo(); 
    element(by.name('email')).sendKeys('...');
    element(by.name('password')).sendKeys('...');
    element(by.buttonText('Log in')).click(); 
    browser.sleep(5000);
    expect(element(by.id('tenantSelect')).isPresent()).toBe(true); 
  });
});
```

So basically this test is the scenario of login in my angular app. When I click in the button 'log in', it triggers API calls and navigate to another component. 'tenantSelect' is an element of my DOM which is displayed when a user is logged, but this element is shown even if there was a failure in one of my HTTP requests. What I want is to catch http requests errors during the process and fail my test.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is resolvers for your components. See the relevant [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data).

Basically, a resolver ensures your API calls (or any other observable) completes before the component is loaded.

Implementing a workaround directly in Protractor config would maybe make your tests green, but when deployed in prod your app would not work as expected and you would see lots of errors in the browser log.

Comment: Since I have many many components in my Angular project, I don't want to have to implement resolvers for all my components of my project, I am just searching a way to access to the response of API calls made by my application. I'll edit my topic to show you an example

Comment: The point of the e2e tests IMO is to simulate real-world interactions that a user could have with your app. When a back-end response is received, it may trigger changes in your UI, which you could test with protractor without catching the API request. Testing that a back-end request occurs, say, on button click, would rather be an integration test; these tests can be written with angular testbed/jasmine/karma/jest or whatever your unit test stack is.

Comment: Just saw your edit, I reiterate: if the expected behaviour of your app is to load the component no matter the API call response, then your app is working fine. If you expect your app to display an error message/404 page or anything else, you should write a test case for this and implement it. You would need to edit your http service to handle the [http errors](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling)

Comment: Thank you for helping me